# Vector Coordinate Image Convert to .bmp or .png

Tags: java, image, vector-graphics

I am using a 3rd party tool which creates a signature image in the form of Vector Coordinates.

The documentation says:

> The value of vector coordinates delimited with a ^ character in the following     format: x1,y1^x2,y2^xN,yN^~ If there is a pen-up event, then you use the coordinate 0, 65535 to signal a break in the line ^ is the coordinate delimiter, ~ is the ending delimiter, and a comma (,) is the vector delimiter

Is there something which can convert the image into a .bmp or .png image?

A simple java class would be ideal.  Or something which can be run at a DOS prompt.

Comment: Probably, but asking for software/libraries is explicitly offtopic. Someone with 3 gold stars should know better than to ask...

Comment: With such a peculiar proprietary format, chances are low that you can find a ready made converter, unless this tool is well spread. On another side, writing one is straightforward. All it takes is a little of parsing and line drawing.